# MNIST handwritten digits dataset - an already decoded version?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, mnist

I looked at many questions and answers about this topic, but they are all about how to parse the original MNIST dataset from Yan Lecun's website (the one encoded in some binary format).

Is there anywhere I can find the images already decoded and available to use as image files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this website, it may be exactly what you look for:

http://mnist-decoded.000webhostapp.com/

Note that the images in this website are in TIFF format - such that it should be exactly what you need, since TIFF format doesn't implement lossy compression and does enable one channel (grayscale) image, such that the data within should be the same data as in the binary encoded file